# How do I use the verb se tenir in order to clarify a point?

Tags: expressions, usage, formulation-idiomatique

I was wondering if any of the following two constructions are used in formal texts in French in order to clarify a point

- Je me tiens de préciser que
- Il me tient de préciser que

Comment: Sur une recherche Google, l'examen de la provenance des résultats laisse à penser à un helvétisme. Ou sinon en ancien français : http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/complement-godefroy/751/10/tenir (importer).

Comment: Consructions inconnues. Pour moi, on dirait tout simplement: _je tiens à préciser que_.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard the first one and would consider it a mistake.

The second might be understood as a very unusual ellipsis of:

> *Il me tient **à cœur** de préciser que[...]*

Answer (score 2):

"Je tiens de préciser que" revient régulièrement (sans "me").
Je l'ai déjà entendu "Je me tiens de préciser que" mais rarement.

« Il tient à préciser que »
« Je me tiens à préciser que »
Le mieux est « à » à la place de « de »
!!!!! Basé sur mon expérience personnelle !!!!!

Comment: Oui, "je tiens de préciser" n'est tout simplement pas correct en langage formel ; le verbe est "tenir à", ce qui signifie "avoir à coeur de", ou plus simplement "vouloir".